# How to deploy a private gem using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler, rvm-capistrano

We have a gem which is specific to our project and is also shared among multiple projects. When we try to install our Gemfile using `bundle:install` command via capistrano, it fails mentioning that it is unable to find the sources for foo-1.0.0.gem

```
** [out :: ubuntu@14.245.216.229] Could not find foo-1.0.0 in any of the sources
```

How should I resolve this, since I cannot expose this gem in a public repository. What would be the right way to bundle and deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should provide the source for the gem like this:

```
gem 'foo', :git => 'https://my_username:my_password@github.com/my_github_account/my_repo.git'
```

If this is not an option for you, you might need to setup your [own gem server](http://olemortenamundsen.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/working-with-private-rubygems-in-rails-3-deploying-to-heroku/) or [vendor the gem](http://underpantsgnome.com/2011/01/05/how-to-install-private-gems-on-heroku)